# Command executes multiple times for menuitems added dynamically to Primefaces SplitButton

Tags: jsf, primefaces, menuitem, split-button

So added primefaces p:splitButton component inside a p:dataView component:

```
<p:dataView var="product" value="bean.products">
   ...
   //for each item in dataView, I add this split button with a couple of menuitem options
   <p:splitButton value="Select Option" icon="pi pi-list" appendTo="@this" model="#{bean.model}" />
   ...
</p:dataView>
```

Building the model:

```
...
DefaultMenuModel menuModel = new DefaultMenuModel();
DefaultMenuItem menuitem = DefaultMenuItem.builder().value("opt1").command("bean.foo1(product)").build();
menumodel.getElements().add(menuitem);
DefaultMenuItem menuitem = DefaultMenuItem.builder().value("opt2").command("bean.foo2(product)").build();
menumodel.getElements().add(menuitem);
```

The p:dataView ends up looking like this

```
---

Product 1
[Select Option^]
 | Opt 1 |
 | Opt 2 |

---

Product 2
[Select Option^]
 | Opt 1 |
 | Opt 2 |

---
...
---

Product 12
[Select Option^]
 | Opt 1 |
 | Opt 2 |

---
```

These are the methods called by the menuitems:

```
public void foo1() {
  System.out.println("first menu item was clicked inside "+product.getName());
}

public void foo2() {
  System.out.println("second menu item was clicked inside "+product.getName());
}
```

So now, when I run the app, this page would display 12 products per page, each with its p:splitButton with the two subitems.

When I click the first menuitem on the first product, it prints a single line as follows:

```
first menu item was clicked inside Product 1
```

When I click a menuitem on any subsequent product, it prints a line for each of the prior products, including the clicked one.

So if I click the first submenu item for the 7th product, it prints out:

```
first menu item was clicked inside Product 1
first menu item was clicked inside Product 2
first menu item was clicked inside Product 3
first menu item was clicked inside Product 4
first menu item was clicked inside Product 5
first menu item was clicked inside Product 6
first menu item was clicked inside Product 7
```

and so forth...

Does anyone know how to avoid this?

Comment: Statically adding subitems does not seem to have this behavior; command executes only once for selected product. I read somewhere that the command property is not the same as the action one, but there doesn't seem to be a method available to add action.

Comment: Don't know what to tell you. I stopped to get a bite to eat and when I got back and continued playing with it and it just stopped doing it. So, please disregard this post for now. Thanks!

Comment: Could you please create a reproducer using https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces-test and share it?